# Android: loading an array of TextViews within a for loop

Tags: android, textview, imagebutton

Hi this is doing my head in, I am trying to load an array of TextViews and ImageButtons within a for loop, i have searched for answers and after my search ended up with code that looked like this:

```
public void initializeVideos() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Titles = new TextView[5];
    Images = new ImageButton[5];
    int tvId;
    int ibId;
    for(int i = 1; i < 6; i++){
        tvId = getResources().getIdentifier("tv" + i, "id", getPackageName());
        ibId = getResources().getIdentifier("ib" + i, "id", getPackageName());
        Titles[i] = (TextView) findViewById(tvId);
        Images[i] = (ImageButton) findViewById(ibId);
    }
}
```

The problem is i am encountering a NumberFormatException and i cannot seem to work out why...

help would be appreciated

Comment: It's going to be string while the is suppose to be int. Debug the returned value from tvId n ibId

Comment: Is the error coming out from the line when first define tvId ? Just by browsing the code, I would expect that you going to end up indexOutOfBound latter as well. But anyway

Answer (score 0):

Yes because of your for loop is wrong here you have to start for loop with i=0 to i<5.
Here problem is that your last id get there are null represent so no id available so it gives you numberformat exception.

Answer (score 0):

The values in the looping is wrong thats y ur getting a Crash ,You are initializing  the value of **i=1**  on the for loop ,so the first value will be placed on the first position of the Arrays and 0th postion of Array remains null, then iteration will continue when it is reach 5 what happen is i will be make a  array out of bound  Exception .It is because of a array size of 5 the position will be like this[0,1,2,3,4] this is the position order of a array of size 5 in the code what will happen is For the last iteration it will put the value in the [5] which is not available in the array.That is causing  the problem;

Working code will be like  this

```
public void initializeVideos() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    TextView[] Titles = new TextView[5];
    ImageButton[] Images = new ImageButton[5];
    int tvId;
    int ibId;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) //Just changed the values in for loop


  {
        System.out.println(i);
        tvId = getResources().getIdentifier("tv" + i, "id",
                getPackageName());
        ibId = getResources().getIdentifier("ib" + i, "id",
                getPackageName());
        Titles[i] = (TextView) findViewById(tvId);
        Images[i] = (ImageButton) findViewById(ibId);
         }
     }
```